# Awk: Length of column number

Tags: bash, awk, floating-point-precision

I have a (maybe) silly question.

My data:
File 1

```
1234.34  a 1235.34 d
3456.23  b 3457.23 e
2325.89  c 2327.89 f
```

I want something like

```
awk '{if($1==$3) print $4}'
```

But of course if I do this, it will print nothing. So I want to modify the "precision" of $3 (in this case)

in the sense that when awk read $3 it finds this:

```
124
345
232
```

then it must be a way to do this, but I don't know it.

```
awk '{if($1==(three digits precision $3)) print $4}'
```

Help?

Comment: Your recent edit changed the question fundamentally: please undo the edit and create a new question instead. Also, you say the output data should come from File 2, but your sample output suggests File 1.

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936117/awk-length-of-column-number-ii

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could calculate the difference of the two values:

```
awk '$1 - $3 < 0.01 || $3 - $1 < 0.01 {print $4}' file
```

Comment: And I was thinking something more complicated haha, thank you! excellent idea.