# Awk: Match column values from 2 files if their numerical values are close

Tags: bash, awk

Following my first question here ([Awk: Length of column number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934069/awk-length-of-column-number))

My data:

File 1

```
8.193506084253E+06 1.900521460E+01
8.193538509494E+06 1.899919490E+01
8.193540934736E+06 1.899317535E+01
8.193543359977E+06 1.898720476E+01
8.193546406105E+06 1.897934066E+01
```

File 2

```
8.193505938557E+06 1.572155163E+01
8.193509618041E+06 1.573016361E+01 
8.193513297526E+06 1.573874442E+01 
8.193516977010E+06 1.574725969E+01
```

I want to take $1 from File 2 and search in File 1 the most closest* value in $1, in order to        get an output like this example

```
 8.193505938557E+06 1.572155163E+01 1.900521460E+01
```

In this case the only the first value of column $1 in file 2 has a match, and nothing else because the other values of $1 from File 2 are not close enough (defining some condition) to any value of $1 from File 1

Note that the number of rows are different.
*closest= where the difference between the two numbers is smaller than some threshold

Comment: Do you still want to match by the _first 3 digits_, as in your original question, or by a delta below a certain threshold (what threshold?)?

Comment: I just want to find the closest number given some difference. For instance since there is no number close to 7589.34, it shouldn't have an output.

Comment: @Nikko Whats your definition of closest?

Comment: I have to define some condition.

Comment: I have change the example for real data

Comment: you still haven't defined "some condition"

Comment: Because in "how" you define the condition, you will solve the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my understanding, according to your description the result should be:

```
1235.34 d a
3457.23 e b
7589.34 f b
```

i.e. including a line for "f" which is closest to "b".

This can be done using the following script:

```
ARGIND == 1 {
    haystack[$1] = $2;
}
ARGIND == 2 {
    bestdiff=-1;
    for (v in haystack)
        if (bestdiff < 0 || (v-$1)**2 < bestdiff) {
            bestkey=haystack[v];
            bestdiff=(v-$1)**2;
        }
    print $1, $2, bestkey;
}
```

(I'm using squaring via `**2` as a substitute for taking the absolute value.)

If you want to suppress results if the difference is for example greater than 10, to get the result you quoted, use something like this:

```
if (bestdiff < 10**2)
    print $1, $2, bestkey;
```

**Edit:** The OP changed the example in- and output in the question. Here are the original example files for reference. File 1:

```
1234.34  a 
3456.23  b 
2325.89  c 
2326.20  c2
```

File 2:

```
1235.34 d
3457.23 e
7589.34 f
```

Output:

```
1235.34 d a
3457.23 e b
```

**Note:** `ARGIND` and `**` are GNU extensions. See comment from mklement0 below for details.

Comment: Can you please help me with the example with the real data?

Comment: Use `if (bestdiff < maxdiff**2)` as condition for the print, with maxdiff being the maximal difference you want to allow. I get the result you quoted with for example `maxdiff=1.0`.

Comment: Perfect, I still don't know how though. But this is the answer! thank you very much!

Comment: You should explain the use of `**2` as a makeshift `abs()` function to avoid confusion; `bestkey` is a bit of a misnomer in that it's not a, _key_ but the (2nd column) value. Compatibility notes: `ARGIND` is a `GNU awk` extension (POSIX-compliant replacement here: `NR==FNR` and `NR!=FNR`); similarly, `**` is not POSIX-compliant, use `^` instead. (Is variable `heystrack` meant to be `haystack`?)

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks for pointing those issues out! I've now replaced "heystack" with "haystack" (oops) and added short notes about `ARGIND` and `**2`. (I generally try do avoid `^` in AWK scripts because it can be mistaken for a XOR operator.)

Comment: Thanks for updating; +1; it's still a `hayst*r*ack`, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Load the first column values into an array for file2.
Then compare the differences using abs function.
The script will output the **closest** match (closest means a single superlative).

```
awk 'BEGIN{closestVal=9999}
     function abs(x){return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)} 

     {
      if (NR==FNR) { f1col2[NR]=$2;v[NR]=$1; next; }

      for (n in v)
      {
        if (abs(v[n] - $1) < closestVal)
        {
            closestVal = abs(v[n] - $1)
            closestLine = $0 " " f1col2[n]
        }
    }
 }   
END {print closestLine}' file1 file2
```

Comment: This would print all matches within a +/- 2 window, not only "the most closest value" as the OP wrote.

Comment: The closest value being *one* value but OP cites two values for results.

Comment: I have put real data now.

Comment: @suspectus: The closes value *for each line in the second file*. This is two lines, when considering the all matches for the 3rd line as to far away. (see my answer for the old example in- and output before OP changed the examples in the question)

Comment: and what I wonder defines "too far away" ?

Comment: "Too far away" means exceeding a threshold for the (absolute) difference in values - while the OP doesn't specify a number for this threshold, the logic can be demonstrated with a variable or sample value.